# Скрипт выключается

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске скрипта, он на секунду включается и сразу выключается. Как это можно исправить? (*Только можно пожалуйста ответ без input и подобного*)

Видеозапись: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/YIj_IC6bD2OSCw

Код bot.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- # строка нужна, чтобы не было ошибки Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd1' in file ...


import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKENBOT = '123123124125125пквчпв'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKENBOT)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def text(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вперёд", callback_data='sokr')
    markup.add(item)
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgQAAxkBAAEDMaJhfpoCVPgHZ_OmGZX_Lh5uIGfTrAAC7QADD6r0B6meFwSQLxsBIQQ")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Можете показать код скрипта bot.py?

Comment: @sigagleb, я бы показал, только он не поместится в комментариях

Comment: очень информативный вопрос :) а почему голосом еще не записали? :)

Comment: Можете добавить код, отредактировав сам вопрос

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно запустить бота, для этого добавьте bot.infinity_polling() в конец скрипта:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKENBOT = '123123124125125пквчпв'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKENBOT)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def text(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вперёд", callback_data='sokr')
    markup.add(item)
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgQAAxkBAAEDMaJhfpoCVPgHZ_OmGZX_Lh5uIGfTrAAC7QADD6r0B6meFwSQLxsBIQQ")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет", reply_markup=markup) 

bot.infinity_polling() # необходимая строчка
```

Рекомендую заново сгенерировать TOKENBOT после успешного запуска

Comment: Точно, забыл. Если бы не вы, я бы не вспомнил, спасибо!

Comment: Рад помочь, можете выбрать мой ответ правильным, если все работает как нужно

Comment: Так и сделаю, через минуту сайт разрешит.